# Meteor + React filters in subscriptions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I'm using meteor and react with withTracker to get dynamic data. I have a large amount of data and i have to filter data on the server side otherwise, the client crash. To do this, i'm using filters as parameters of publications.

The problem is the component doesn't update when i change one field of the query which is already in the past request. To solve this, i add or remove a {"_id":{$exists:true}} to make the component refresh and not use cache data.

Server side publication :

```
Meteor.publish('subredOrders', function(filters={}, sort={"_id":1}, pagination={skip:0,limit:2000}, fields={}) {
    return SubredOrders.find(filters, {sort: sort, skip: pagination.skip, limit: pagination.limit, fields: fields});
});

Meteor.publish('subredOrders.count', function(filters={}) {
    Counts.publish(this, 'subredOrders.count', SubredOrders.find(filters), {fastCount: true});
});
```

Client side component :

```
class MyTable extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            filtersPanel: false,
        };
        this.temp = {filters: this.props.params.filters};
    }

    toggleFiltersPanel(){
        let filtersPanel = this.state.filtersPanel;
        filtersPanel = !filtersPanel;
        *if (!filtersPanel) {
            if (this.temp.filters["$and"] && this.temp.filters["$and"].length > 0) {
                let removed = false;
                for(let i=0; i < this.temp.filters["$and"].length; i++){
                    for(let key in this.temp.filters["$and"][i]) {
                        if (key === "_id") {
                            this.temp.filters["$and"].splice(i, 1);
                            removed = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!removed) this.temp.filters["$and"].push({"_id":{$exists:true}});
            }
            this.props.updateParams("filters", this.temp.filters);
        }*
        this.setState({filtersPanel: filtersPanel});
    }

    ...

    render() {
        ...
    }
}

export default withTracker((props) => {
    if (props.collector == null) return {};
    let sub = Meteor.subscribe(props.subscription, props.params.filters, props.params.sort, props.params.pagination);
    let countSub = Meteor.subscribe(props.subscription+".count", props.params.filters);

    return {
        collection: props.collector.find({}, {limit: props.params.pagination.limit}).fetch(),
        dataLoaded: sub.ready() && countSub.ready(),
    }
})(MyTable);
```

My solution is between the 2 *. When the user close the filtersPanel it launchs toggleFiltersPanel and check if the filters part of the request has _id or not, and it push or remove to make it deferent from the past one. If the user change 2 times one field, the request works only the first time. That's why i have to do this, but i don't understand why ...

It's not an optimized solution and maybe someone has an other idea or can at least explain me why i have to do this to make it works ?

Thank you !